# makefile ignore removed file names

Tags: makefile

A directory with css files in it and for each file in the directory I want a separate minified `.min.css` file in the same directory.

So for example `my.css` get minified into `my.min.css` in the same directory.

First I tried

```
css/*.css:
    uglifycss $@ > $(subst .css,.min.css,$@)
```

`make -B` yeaaa victorie its working :D

But after doing `make -B` again I get a new separate file each time resulting in `my.min.css` `my.min.min.css` `my.min.min.min.css`

Then I tried

```
.PHONY: clean

css/*.css: clean
    uglifycss $@ > $(subst .css,.min.css,$@)

clean:
    -rm css/*.min.css
```

DOH! after clean it is still remembering the files it deleted in the first place resulting again in a `my.min.min.min.css` file

How can I tell make to stop doing `my.min.min.min.css`?

(make: GNU Make 3.81 OSX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get a list of all files with the suffix .css:

```
ALL := $(wildcard *.css)
```

then remove files that have the suffix .me.css:

```
NEW := $(filter-out %.me.css,$(ALL))
```

and add the suffix to remaining files:

```
ME := $(patsubst %.css,%.me.css,$(NEW))
```

Then you add those files as prerequisites to the default target, and add you own recipe that builds those files, in this case a simple echo:

```
%.me.css:
    echo 123 > $@

default: $(ME)
```

Compared to your approach, this has the benefit that you don't have to use the flag -B, as only the files that need to be built are built. Therefore invoking make is done by simply caling make without any targets or flags (assuming the makefile is named makefile or Makefile):

```
make
```